# Python argparse: default argument stored as string, not list

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I cannot figure out this behaviour of argparse from the documentation:

```
import argparse

parser.add_argument("--host", metavar="", dest="host", nargs=1, default="localhost", help="Name of host for database.  Default is 'localhost'.")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Here is the output with and without an argument for "--host":

```
>> python demo.py
Namespace(host='localhost')

>> python demo.py --host host
Namespace(host=['host'])
```

In particular: why does the argument to "--host" get stored in a list when it is specified but not when the default is used?

Comment: Because you specified `nargs=1`. When `nargs` is present, because you can set `nargs` to `+` or a larger number, the results are stored in a `list`. But the default is given as a string. You can write `default=["localhost"]` and the default will be a list as well.

Comment: Thanks.  Totally missed that.

Comment: the `default` is added to the namespace as is (apart from any conversion that the `type` might do).  `nargs` and `action` don't, for the most part, affect it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Remove the "nargs" keyword argument. Once that argument is defined argparse assumes your argument is a list (nargs=1 meaning a list with 1 element)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative and handy module: [Docopt](http://docopt.org/) can be used for parsing command line arguments. Docopt transform a commandline into a dictionnary by defining values inside **doc**.

Answer (score 1):

The question title and the question body ask two different questions. This is potentially a sign of the confusion I shared with the OP.

The title: *why is the default a string not a list?*
The body: *why is the given value a list not a string?*

The selected answer provides the solution to the question in the body. The answer to the question in the title is:

The entry `default="localhost"` sets `default` to `"localhost"`, which is a sting. To set it as a list, you could use: `default=["localhost"]`.

Comment: It's a little unclear whether the OP is puzzled more by the value being a list (as you were), or the default not being a list.  The final question could be interpreted either way.

Comment: Agreed - I've edited my answer to point out that confusion, rather than say it's misleading.